# Python: How to merge two lists like a zip with for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I am given a problem where I have a function that takes two integer lists and returns a single integer list (new list) with the two integer lists zipped together.

For example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
```

Should give `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]` not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Another case is if one list is longer than another, e.g:

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [4,5,6,9]
```

Once the shorter list runs out of items, the longer list should add its remaining elements. E.g: `[1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9]`

I have tried using conditional statements to check which list is longer and use a for loop to append to a new list that should be returned. I tried using for loops that loop for the duration of the shorter list, and once the for loop is over, it adds the remaining elements from longer list to the new list. Also if both lists are empty I have to return an empty new list.

The code:

```
def main():
    list1 = [1,2]
    list2 = [4,5,6,9]
    print(zip_lists(list1, list2))

def zip_lists(list1, list2):
    new_list = []

    if len(list1) > len(list2):
        last_num = list1[len(list1):]
        for num in range(0, len(list2)):
            new_list.append(list1[num])
            new_list.append(list2[num])
        new_list.append(last_num)
        return new_list

    elif len(list2) > len(list1):
        last_num = list2[len(list2):]
        for num in range(0, len(list1)):
            new_list.append(list1[num])
            new_list.append(list2[num])
        new_list.append(last_num)
        return new_list


    elif len(list1) and len(list2) == 0:
        return new_list


main()
```

However, I have a problem where I cannot add the remaining elements from the longer list and instead returns a partially zipped list with empty square brackets.

The test case:

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [4,5,6,9]
```

Should be [1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9] but I'm getting [1, 4, 2, 5, []].

Is my code showing the right way of thinking about this problem?

Comment: In the situation of `elif len(list2) > len(list1)`  `last_num` should be   `list2[len(list1):] `... and `new_list+=last_num`. same error in another situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def zip_lists(list1, list2):
    n1=len(list1)
    n2=len(list2)
    k = []
    n = min(n1, n2)
    for i in range(n):
        k.append(list1[i])
        k.append(list2[i])

    if n1==n2:
        return k 
    if n1>n2:
        return k+list1[n:]
    else:
        return k+list2[n:]
```

---

Test:

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [4,5,6,9]
zip_lists(list1, list2)
```

Output: `[1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to do that like:

#### Code:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def merge(l1, l2):
    for i in zip_longest(l1, l2):
        for j in i:
            if j is not None:
                yield j
```

#### Test Code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
ans1 = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]

list3 = [1, 2]
list4 = [4, 5, 6, 9]
ans2 = [1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9]

assert list(merge(list1, list2)) == ans1
assert list(merge(list3, list4)) == ans2
```

Answer (score 1):

A general version of this (i.e., for any number of source iterables, of possibly different lengths) is shown in the Python documentation for the [`itertools` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), named `roundrobin` in the ["recipes" section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Copied here, with the original credit:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Here, `cycle` and `islice` are the functions provided by `itertools` (`from itertools import cycle, islice`); the rest is built-in. Note that this is a generator, not a normal function; you will need to iterate over it yourself (or directly create e.g. a list from it, e.g. `merged = list(roundrobin(list1, list2))`).

---

As far as debugging your attempt at the code, let's consider the case where `list1` is longer (the case where `list2` is longer has parallel problems; and the case where they're equal is working fine, yes?):

```
    last_num = list1[len(list1):] # problem 1
    for num in range(0, len(list2)):
        new_list.append(list1[num])
        new_list.append(list2[num])
    new_list.append(last_num) # problem 2
```

Problem 1: you want to extract the "excess" elements from `list1`, which you determine as all the ones past a certain point. This is just a typo or not thinking about it clearly; you want to use the length of *`list2`* for the number of elements to slice off; of course, using the length of `list1` to remove elements from `list1` removes everything.

Problem 2: you have a list whose elements you want to concatenate to the end of another list. `.append` treats its parameter as a single new list element, *even if it's a list*; like the Zen of Python says, `special cases aren't special enough to break the rules` (keep in mind that sometimes you might *want* to do this, after all). The method you're looking for, instead, is `.extend`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
l=len(a) if len(a)<len(b) else len(b)
a=np.array(list1[:l])
b=np.array(list2[:l])
ab=np.vstack((a, b)).T.flatten()
res=list(ab)+list1[l:]+list2[l:]
```

Comment: It is difficult to explain in detail because numpy is scientific computing library. T is matrix transpose.